# Replacing occurences like "f(x)=", "g(x)=" → "*(x)" in string using javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Obviously I don't know how to formulate my question correctly because I could not find an answer. So I am sorry in case this is a duplicate.

My recent problem: I get user strings, such as `f(x)=3x;g(x)=sin(x);2x;cos(x)` and I need to replace all the `*(x)=`. So that I finally get: `3x;sin(x);2x;cos(x)`

I guess this is a job for a regex, but I am a regex-noob...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
'f(x)=3x;g(x)=sin(x);2x;cos(x)'.replace(/\w+\(x\)=/g, '');
```